# Enable button without exposing model properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using the MVVM pattern with [MVVMHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers).

I already made the login form, but I was trying to enable the button only if the user has typed his username and password.

```
public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

    private string _Username;
    public string Username {
        get { return _Username; }
        set {
            if (_Username != value) {
                _Username = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                Activate();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Password;
    public string Password {
        get { return _Password; }
        set {
            if (_Password != value) {
                _Password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                Activate();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _IsEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled {
        get { return _IsEnabled; }
        set {
            if (_IsEnabled != value) {
                _IsEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Activate() {  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) {
            IsEnabled = true;
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public LoginVM() {
        LoginCommand = new Command(() => {
            MessageBox.Show("LogeIn");    
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I achieved this, by exposing the properties of the class to my VM.
I was wondering if there is a way to do this without exposing it?
https://github.com/eduardoagr?tab=repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* achieve this in XAML only, by using a multi-binding on the `IsEnabled` property on the *Sign In* `Button` to the user name and the password `TextBox`es along with a custom value converter that converts the bound `string`s to a `bool` that indicates whether they are empty or not.

However, in this case that is not possible, since you should avoid using `Command` and `IsEnabled` at the same time, as it can lead to strange behavior. Commands offer a mechanism to determine, if an action is possible or not and [will in turn set the `IsEnabled` state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#what-are-commands).

> A command can indicate whether an action is possible by implementing the CanExecute method. A button can subscribe to the CanExecuteChanged event and be disabled if CanExecute returns false or be enabled if CanExecute returns true.

As you can see, setting both a `Command` and `IsEnabled` will interfere with each other. Although it might work, if you specify `IsEnabled` before `Command` in XAML, this is a brittle solution, so choose one, in this case favor `Command` with its built in mechanism.

The good news is that instead of doing this in XAML, you can achieve the same in your view model and save yourself some code by passing a `CanExecute` delegate to your `LoginCommand` as follows.

```
public class LoginVM : ViewModelBase {

    public Command LoginCommand { get; }

    private string _Username;
    public string Username {
        get { return _Username; }
        set {
            if (_Username != value) {
                _Username = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    private string _Password;
    public string Password {
        get { return _Password; }
        set {
            if (_Password != value) {
                _Password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public LoginVM() {
        LoginCommand = new Command(
           () => MessageBox.Show("Log IN"),
           () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password));
    }
}
```

The second parameter for your command is a method that determines, whether the command *can execute* and if it returns `true`, the control that binds the command will automatically be enabled or disabled when returning `false`. Using this approach, you do not need the `IsEnabled` property at all and you can **remove it from XAML**.

The only other thing to note here is that you have to tell the `LoginCommand`, when it needs to reevaluate the `CanExecute` delegate by calling its `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method (defined in  the `Command` class). In order to access it, change the type of the property from `ICommand` to `Command` or define a separate backing field for it. In this case, it needs to be reevaluated each time either `Username` or `Password` changes, so put it in their setters.

At the moment, the `TextBox`es for the user name and password update the view model properties only when losing focus (e.g. clicking outside of it or another control). If you want the *Sign In* button to react on each keystroke, change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`.

```
<inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout x:Name="sfTextInputLayout"
                               Hint="Username"
                               Margin="20,20,20,0">
    <TextBox Foreground="BlanchedAlmond"
             Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</inputLayout:SfTextInputLayout>
<controls:CustomPasswordBox Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Thank I did it but I  have another problem